# Add unique element to ArrayList with "dynamic" suffix

Tags: java

I have seen similar question in Stack , but it was for files in C.
The situation :
I have an ArrayList of Strings , which element is an e-mail.For example:

```
jony@test.com
jony1@test.com
gerd@test.com
```

etc.

i want to write a function/method which will add a new e-mail to that List with one very important catch !:

if for example i want to add "jony@test.com" , the method should go through the 
    ArrayList and if "jony@test.com" already exist, then it checkes if "jony1@test.com" exists etc, until it finds free number suffix, and then add it.In our example it should add "jony2@test.com".

The problem is that i want some short and elegant sollution, what i wrote is 
   ugly 150 lines of code with 3 methods etc, which just doesnt look ok.
Anyone with a nice algorithm or perhaps advanced Collection feaute to accomplish that ?

Thanks

Comment: You should visit the Stackexchange for Code Review. Besides that.. 150 loc for that?...

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a Set instead of a List, it would cut the verification process.

Comment: Instead of a list I'd probably use a set for performance reasons. Then you'd basically do the following: 1) split the email into the parts before and after the `@`, 2) check whether the email already exists in the set, 3) if it exists you start a loop that increments a number, builds the email to check as `parts[0] + number + "@" + parts[1]` and checks for that email - if it is present you increment the number and try again, if it isn't you add it and break the loop. That should be somewhere around 10 lines. - Please try it and if you have difficulties post the code you already have.

Comment: initially i thought of a Set , but the problem is that i will need to get the elements by index , so a sorted way

Comment: How should this behave if you input jony1@test.com, in the list? Should it add jony11@test.com or jony2@test.com or there won't be such input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check your list before adding, like this:

```
public void addWithSuffix(String email) {
    if(list.contains(email)) {
        int number = 0;
        String[] tmp = email.split("@");

        for(; list.contains(tmp[0] + number + "@" + tmp[1]); number++){}

        list.add((tmp[0] + number + "@" + tmp[1]));
    }
    else {
        list.add(email);
    }
}
```

But, of course, validating your inputs to ensure that the email is valid before trying to add it. And I'd also recommend swapping a `List` for a `Set`

Comment: Thanks,that was it, i couldnt come up with that, because i have forgotten that for loop can be used that way .Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Create custom add method and use split in value and check till the count of reaches max values,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomListAdd {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        add("jony@test.com",list);
        add("jony@test.com",list);
        add("jony@test.com",list);
        add("jony@test.com",list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    public static void add(String value,List<String> list) {
        if(list.contains(value)) {
            int count = 1;
            String[] strSplited = value.split("@");

            while(list.contains(strSplited[0] + count + "@" + strSplited[1]))
                count++;
            list.add((strSplited[0] + count + "@" + strSplited[1]));
        }
        else {
            list.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DynamicMail{

private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String args[]){
    DynamicMail dm = new DynamicMail();
    dm.addToList("jony@test.com");
    dm.addToList("gary@test.com");
    dm.addToList("jony@test.com");
    dm.addToList("jony@test.com");
    dm.addToList("jony@test.com");
    dm.addToList("gary@test.com");
    dm.addToList("ghost@test.com");

    System.out.println(dm.getEmails());
}

public Map<String, Integer> getMap(){
    return map;
}

public List<String> getEmails(){
    return emails;
}

public void addToList(String email){
    String[] parts = email.split("@");
    Integer i = map.computeIfAbsent(parts[0], x->new Integer(0));
    if(i!=0)
        emails.add(parts[0]+i+"@"+parts[1]);
    else
        emails.add(email);
    map.put(parts[0], ++i);

}
}
```

This will work assuming you are starting with an empty list and emails like jony1@test.com or gerd2@test.com won't be the input.

Comment: Very elegant !Thanks too

Answer (score 0):

> try this
>
> Main class

```
List <String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("jony@test.com");
    list.add("jony1@test.com");
    list.add("jony2@test.com");
    list.add("jony3@test.com");
    list.add("gerd@test.com");
    String newEmail = "jony@test.com";
    String last = "";
    for (String string : list) {
        if(compareString(newEmail , string)){
            last = string;
        }
    }
    int newNumber = Integer.valueOf(last.substring(last.indexOf("@")-1, last.indexOf("@")))+1;
    String[] s = newEmail.split("@");
    list.add(s[0]+ newNumber + s[1]);
    System.out.println(list);
```

> compare string after replacing digits

```
private static boolean compareString(String string, String string2) {
    string2 = string2.replaceAll("\\d","");
    return string.equals(string2);
}
```